# Is it possible to get column names from an ArcSDESQLExecute SELECT execution

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I am running ArcGIS 10.0 desktop and querying an Oracle 11g database and writing the results of a SELECT statement out to a CSV file. Everything works great; however, I would love to find a way to include the column names in the CSV without hard coding them.

My code looks like this:

```
obj_sde_conn_ora = arcpyArcSDESQLExecute(server, port, "#", user, password)

sql_ora_select = """SELECT col1, col2
FROM tab"""

sde_return = obj_sde_conn_ora.execute(sql_ora_select)
csv_file = open(out_csv, "wb")
import csv
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for row in sde_return:
    csv_writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf8", "replace") for s in row])
del sde_return
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: I'm working on the same problem. Have you ever found a way to extract field/column names with ArcSDESQLExecute?

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of columns for a table in Oracle using ALL_TAB_COLUMNS from this query using ArcSDESQLExecute...

```
select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'.
```

The returned list may need to be processed to eliminate unwanted columns.

Comment: Cheers for the response. I am aware of the SQL metadata tables; however, this approach won't work with joins, subqueries, casts, functions etc. I would like to be able to get the columns of any SELECT query. Something like the currsor.description in cx_oracle - http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cursor.html